# Issue with window.location.href and page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got some code to redirect to a certain page if a certain condition is true

```
 if(value.match(/^<?php echo $javascriptArray; ?>$/))
        {
            window.location.href = '/postcode-success/?pc='+value;

        }
```

On the page that the user is redirected to I've got a php if statement that will show a topbanner:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['pc_valid'] !=null) :?>
<div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
    <div class="success-container" id="success-top">
        <p>Success! <?php echo $_SESSION['pc']; ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif?>
```

Now this all works but the problem is that you need to refresh the page in order for the `pc_valid` if statement to work and the banner to show.
I'm not sure why this is or how to fix it?
I guess I need to somehow reload the page on redirect?

Comment: Cowboy solution `if (!$_SESSION['pc_valid']) {window.location.reload();}` lol #bewareOfEndlessReloads

Comment: You could simply add the current timestamp as a cache buster, if you don’t mind it showing up in the URL.

Comment: `<?php if ($_GET['pc'] =="....") $_SESSION["pc_valid"]="something"; ?><?php if ($_SESSION['pc_valid'] !=null) :?>`

Comment: @gotomanners cowboy non-sense solution. You mix on one instruction two different languages for different purposes. I don't know who upvote your comment...

Comment: I can't understand where you read on javascript a `<?php` sentence. Maybe you are not running on server?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude maybe it was the person that actually caught the joke!

Answer (score 0):

re-write with [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) type solution?

Here's a jQuery option: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#success-top').load(document.URL +  ' #newBanner');
```

---

```
if(value.match(/^<?php echo $javascriptArray; ?>$/)) {
    $('#success-top').load(document.URL +  ' #newBanner');
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Cage. Is this an answer?

Comment: I'm suggesting a client side, ajax solution may work, if he re-writes some things, yes. AJAX methods are designed for scenarios like this. He included the tag 'JavaScript'.